# How regex should be if I want to check if sub directory is optional?

Tags: python, regex

I want that type_dir is optional directory.

I use search. is it Ok ?
Do I need use try...except block ?

```
import re
pattern = r'mydir/.*(\w*).*/\[{type_dir}\]/'.format(type_dir="")
```

For example,

```
type_dir = b
mydir/a/b/c - True
mydir/a/c - True
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, you want to use regex to find a way to check if a certain directory exists or not where any sub-directories are optional.

So, my answer is that you don't need to use `try... except` and search is perfectly fine. A faster way for searching is to use `glob` python module like so:

Note: the folder hierarchy inside `mydir` is as the following:

[image]

```
>>> import os
>>> from glob import glob
>>>
>>> type_dir = "b"
>>> print(glob(os.path.join("mydir", "**", type_dir), recursive=True))
['mydir/a/b']
>>>
>>> type_dir = "c"
>>> print(glob(os.path.join("mydir", "**", type_dir), recursive=True))
['mydir/a/c', 'mydir/a/b/c']
>>>
>>> type_dir = "d"
>>> print(glob(os.path.join("mydir", "**", type_dir), recursive=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

An optional string means the string is matching zero or one time. There is a symbol for it `?`, see [RE syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

The RE string for [re.fullmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) would be

```
/dir/(subdir/)?file
```

and will match `/dir/subdir/file` and `/dir/file` and nothing else.

---

For completness: the basic RE for any optional subdirs is:

```
/dir/(.*/)?file
```

which will match  the file directly in the dir `/dir/file` or in some subdir `/dir/sub/file`, also even several levels deep `/dir/sub1/sub2/file`.

If you want to restrict the optional subdir to one level only:

```
/dir/([^/]*/)?file
```